# What's the main difference between stdlib.h and cstdlib in C++?

Tags: c++

I'm using EXIT_FAILURE macro, so I need to include stdlib.h or cstdlib. But I don't know what the difference is. Should I use cXXX style header file rather than XXX.h?

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between cstdlib and stdlib.h?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900785/whats-the-difference-between-cstdlib-and-stdlib-h)

Comment: Check out my updated answer here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13889467/should-i-include-xxxx-h-or-cxxxx-in-c-programs/43016708#43016708

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As EXIT_FAILURE is a macro, it makes no difference which you include. The `cstdlib` version will put the names of all the functions into the `std` namespace, so you can say things like:

```
std::exit(0);
```

but as macros don't respect namespaces, you can't say:

```
std::EXIT_FAILURE
```

Comment: Thanks, but I can still call `exit(EXIT_FAILURE)` without `std::` when I include `cstdlib`.

Comment: @Brian Yes, the exit function will be in both the global and the std  namespaces,

Comment: Also, some overloads are declared to deal with [constness problem of strtol()](http://www.cpptalk.net/strtol-const-ness-problem-vt54984.html) and similar issues.

Answer (score 29):

`<cstdlib>` is just `<stdlib.h>` wrapped in the `std` namespace. You should use `<cstdlib>` in order to be keep your global namespace clean.