# How to call execute command line in C++

Tags: c++

For example, I have a script ./helloworld.sh

I would like to call it in C++, how do I do that? Which library can be used?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try

```
system("./helloworld.sh");
```

Comment: It's in the "<cstdlib>" header, or "<stdlib.h>" if you like that better.

Comment: It should be `std::system` when you include `<cstdlib>` - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900785/

Answer (score 5):

If you just want to run it (and nothing else)

```
system("./helloworld.sh");
```

If you need to get the stdin/stdout then you need to use popen()

```
FILE*  f = popen("./helloworld.sh","r");
```

Answer (score 3):

try [system()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/system).

Answer (score 1):

In C there are also the [`execxxx` functions](http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man3/execl.3.asp) from `unistd.h`. They have a big advantage over the simple `system` as you can specify environment variables for your process to run in among other levels of control for the arguments management.

Comment: What would he be willing to do with an bash sh file under Windows? :-)

Comment: You would also lose control of the c++ program wouldn't you?  If I remember, exec never returns.

Comment: @KLee1, you are absolutely right, the process is replaced... Not such a good idea in cases you want to control the stuff after all. I forgot that.

Comment: IMO system is the way to go, since its platform independent, and specifying environment variables isnt a problem at all, since you can set the desired environment variables beforehand with more `system` calls (i am thinking of set/export). Btw @jdehaan, MSYS supports sh files.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two possible ways. 
*(I suppose you are asking about Unix-like systems when using shell scripts)*.

The first one is very simple, but is blocking (it returns after the command has been completed):

```
/* Example in pure C++ */
#include <cstdlib>
int ret = std::system("/home/<user>/helloworld.sh");

/* Example in C/C++ */
#include <stdlib.h>
int ret = system("/home/<user>/helloworld.sh");
```

The second way is not that easy, but could be non-blocking (script can be run as parallel process):

```
/* Example in C/C++ */
#include <unistd.h>
pid_t fork(void);
int execv(const char *path, char *const argv[]);

/* You have to fork process first. Search for it, if you don't know how to do it.
 * In child process you have to execute shell (eg. /bin/sh) with one of these
 * exec* functions and you have to pass path-to-your-script as the argument.
 * If you want to get script output (stdout) on-the-fly, you can do that with
 * pipes. Just create the reading pipe in parent process before forking
 * the process and redirect stdout to the writing pipe in the child process.
 * Then you can just use read() function to read the output whenever you want.
 */
```

Comment: since the OP asked for a C++ way, you should not mention things like fork/execv... and btw, when you use fork already, there is no reason to use execv instead of execv, or is there ?

Answer (score 0):

if you also want to get the output of the script do

```
char fbuf[256];
char ret[2555]; 
FILE *fh;
if ((fh = popen("./helloworld.sh", "r")) == NULL) {
    return 0;
}else{
    while ( fgets(fbuf, sizeof(fbuf), fh) ) {   
     strcat(ret, fbuf);            
     }          
}
pclose(fh);
```