# String not defined in scope. Unsure why

Tags: c++, scope

so I've been picking up C++ during my free time, and I'm trying to build a simple rock paper scissors game. I get a "not defined in this scope error" for x, y and z when I try to run this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>


int main(){

  string x,y,z;

  srand (time(NULL));
  int computer = rand() % 3 + 1;
  int user = 0;

  std::cout << "====================\n";
  std::cout << "rock paper scissors!\n";
  std::cout << "====================\n";

  std::cout << "1) ✊\n";
  std::cout << "2) ✋\n";
  std::cout << "3) ✌️\n";

  std::cout << "shoot! ";

  std::cin >> user;

  if(user== 1){


    x = (computer == 3) ? "You win!" : "You lose.";
    std::cout<<x;

  }else if(user==2){


    y = (computer == 1) ? "You win!" : "You lose.";
    std::cout<<y;

  }else{

    if(user == 3){

      z = (computer == 2) ? "You win!" : "You lose.";
      std::cout<<z;

    }

  }


}
```

What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Also: In C++ projects, prefer `<cstdlib>` to `<stdlib.h>`.

Comment: Recommendation: In future questions copy the complete error message into the question. It makes it easier for answers to tell what went wrong (you get an answer faster) and makes it easier for future askers to find and understand the question and its answers.

Comment: @ReinstateMonica further documentation if you wonder why you should prefer `<cstdlib>` over `<stdlib.h>`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900785/whats-the-difference-between-cstdlib-and-stdlib-h

Answer (score 5):

You have `string x,y,z;` but `string` belongs to the namespace `std`.

Your `cout` works because you typed `std::cout` in your code. Do the same thing with these strings because you don't have a `using namespace std;` in your code.

**Solution:**

Change `string x,y,z;` to `std::string x,y,z;`

**Aside:**

You are also missing the header `<ctime>` for `srand(time(NULL));`