# why getenv() can get name resolved without a std::?

Tags: c++, getenv, token-name-resolution

getenv() has a C++ implementation which can be included in the header file . So it is a member of namespace std. However, the getenv() function can be get resolved correctly in my code even without a std::getenv(), which means my follow program can be compiled and run without any error and warning. So why getenv() as a name member of namespace std can get resolved without std::? My OS and compiler is Ubuntu 12.04 i386 and g++ 4.8.1 respectively.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char * path_env;

    path_env = getenv("PATH"); //without a name resolve operation std::getenv()

    std::cout << path_env << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's [optional](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7596439/962089) whether the functions are in the global namespace as well as `std` when including `cstdlib`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use search before asking questions. This is duplicate of [why and how does rand() exist both in global and std namespace in cstdlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15037456/why-and-how-does-rand-exist-both-in-global-and-std-namespace-in-cstdlib)

**C++11 Standard: D.5 C standard library headers**
**Para 3:**

> The header `<cstdlib>` assuredly provides its declarations and definitions within the namespace `std`. It may also provide these names within the global namespace. The header `<stdlib.h>` assuredly provides the same declarations and definitions within the global namespace, much as in the C Standard. It may also provide these names within the namespace `std`.

Comment: You should vote to close it as a duplicate rather than posting an answer.

Comment: i have no idea how to do that.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that you need 3000 reputation points to do that. Once you get that privilege, there will be a "close" link at the bottom of each question. Meanwhile, it's probably better to post a comment on the question pointing to the duplicate; a higher-rep user can then vote to close it. http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/

Answer (score 1):

When you `include` one of the c* headers, the standard *requires* that the names are in the `std` namespace, but *allows* them to be first placed into the global namespace and then copied over to `std`.

Conversely, when you `include` one of the *.h headers (which are deprecated), the standard *requires* that the names are placed into the global namespace, but *allows* them to be first declared in the `std` namespace and copied over.

From [headers] / 4

> [...] It is unspecified whether these names are first declared within the
>   global namespace scope and are then injected into namespace std by
>   explicit using-declarations (7.3.3).

From [depr.c.headers]

[image]

Technically for maximum portability you should prefix names (except macros of course) in the c* headers with `std`, although in my limited experience I haven't come across an implementation that doesn't declare them in the global namespace as well.

Comment: Interesting, can you provide a quote from the standard? I wouldn't have allowed that though, as it may create un-portable code.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is probably not portable. BTW, it [seems to work](http://ideone.com/TpgiHb) even without including `<cstdlib>`. If we look carefully at the declaration:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/getenv

we see that indeed it belongs to `cstdlib`, and the usual convention is that all headers that starts with `c` + previous C-like header are now in `namespace std;`, so you should be using `std::`.

Same happens with `std::string`, seems to be included by many standard library headers, although if you look at the standard, you shouldn't rely on this.